# Nesbot Carbon difference: How to round to the nearest month

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I have a pair of dates (start and end):

**Example 1**:
Start date: 2018-01-01
End date: 2018-06-30

**Example 2**:
Start date: 2017-06-07
End date: 2017-12-31

When I apply the following

```
return $this->end_date->diffForHumans($this->start_date,true);
```

to the example 1, I get the following result:
"*5 months*"

then, when I apply the following

```
return $this->end_date->diffForHumans($this->start_date,true);
```

to the example 2, I get the following result:
"*6 months*"

How can I set carbon up or work it around to show "6 months" in the first example, i mean, to round it to the closest month number?
Because in the first example, it is more than 5 months and a half, so to me it'd be better to get "6 months" as result, or even better "5 months and a half".

I have tried all the params explained in the [docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff) but no luck.

Comment: The first example is actually a whole 6 months. You're going from 1st January to the 30th June. I'm not sure why you think this would be better displayed as _5 months and a half_. If anything, it should be displayed as _6 months_.

Comment: I agree. Then how can I make it result as 6 months (nearest month number)?

Comment: Have you considered the `diffInMonths()` method?

Comment: Yeah, I'd already considered and tried that and got the same result.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do it with `Carbon` alone. Instead, I think you'll need a custom function. If you use `$end->diff($start)`, you can then get the difference in days. Dividing that by an average of 30.41 days in a month, and taking the ceiling value, you can round up to the nearest month.

Answer (score 1):

Rounding is supported as of version 2.27. It's not yet documented but you'd do something like this:

```php
return $this->end_date->diffForHumans($this->start_date, ['parts' => 1, 'options' => CarbonInterface::ROUND]);
```

You can read more on [this Github issue](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/559#issuecomment-557104313).